# Updating a static website hosted on an AWS S3 Bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I need a better way to update a static website that is hosted in an AWS S3 bucket.

Whenever I am wanting to update my personal site that I have hosted through a S3 bucket, I have to deleting the index.html file and the assets folder from the S3 bucket, then re-upload the new files. I am doing this through the AWS web interface. Is there a way to use a different AWS service to do this in a way similar to git where I can push updated code? Possibly with lambda?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant automate the whole process using Continous Integration and Deployment. The  architecture in the simplest form looks like this :

1. Setup AWS Code Pipeline to trigger a lambda function on any new code commit in your repo(github,bitbucket,etc)
2. The lambda can do the task of updating your S3 content

A more sophisticated architecture can be referred at https://github.com/alestic/aws-git-backed-static-website. Here is the architecture sourced from the same source

[image]

Comment: OK, so I would connect my repo to the Pipeline and whenever that repo is updated,  I can have it trigger a Lambda function to replace the old repo with the new repo. If I'm following correctly.

Comment: Yes thats correct. This pipeline gives you much more flexibilty how you want to build and deploy stuff. Even if you would like to replace the deployment from S3 to ec2-instance, you may only need to update the lambda.

Comment: Great! Thanks for being so informed and helpful! Can't wait till I can answer peoples question!

Answer (score 1):

You can use AWC CLI tools for update code in S3 bucket.
You Need to configure AWS CLI in your local system with your AWS account.
you can download the AWS CLI from below links

1. For Windows 64 bit: https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-cli/AWSCLI64.msi
2. For Windows 32 bit: https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-cli/AWSCLI32.msi

you can copy your code to your bucket like

```
aws s3 cp yourcode s3://yourbucket/yourcode
```

Comment: Or better yet: `aws s3 sync localdir s3://yourbuket/folder/`

Comment: This approach is simplistic but problematic for any production use such as website hosting. The main flaw here is that code is not sync from a repo, local changes may get deployed and can be completely out of sync from repo, which means others don't know what is deployed and where is the code.