# updating an S3 website with zero downtime

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

What would be the best approach to update a static website hosted on an S3 bucket such that there is no downtime. The updates will be done by marketing teams of a company with zero knowledge of cli commands or how to move around in the console. Are there ways to achieve this without having to learn to move around in the console?

**Edit**

The web site is a collection of static html pages and will be updated using an Html editor. Once edited the marketing team will upload each individual updated file to the S3 bucket. There are no more than 10 such files including html and images. This was currently being hosted on a shared server and we now want to move it to an S3 bucket capable of hosting simple web pages. The preference is to not provision console access for certain users as they are comfortable only using a WYSIWYG html editor and uploading using an FTP client. The editors don't know html and the site doesn't use javascript. I am thinking of writing a batch script to manage the uploads to keep all that cli complexity away so they only work on the HTML in the editor. Looking for the simplest approach to achieve this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58552560/updating-a-static-website-hosted-on-an-aws-s3-bucket/58552914#58552914

Comment: How heavily is your website being used? Are there really people hitting it continuously? Your problem is not "downtime", but rather the possibility that a page might refer to a resource that does not exist during the update period. If there are only 10 files, then the update probably only takes a few seconds. What is the worst-case if somebody tried to access during that time and there was a broken link?

Comment: Its a website that mostly has news articles and links to other more heavily used websites deployed on EC2 instances. The site gets between 1000-2000 visitors a month. Traffic is lower on weekends, but the marketing team also doesn't work weekends :) If there was a broken link someone might get an older discount code or get redirected to an older article on a different website.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a CI/CD pipeline as mentioned here

[Update static website in an automated way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58552560/updating-a-static-website-hosted-on-an-aws-s3-bucket/58552914#58552914)

The above pipeline generally has a code commit as trigger. It depends what your marketing teams are doing on the content and how they are updating it. If they are updating the content that is hosted on AWS, you can change the trigger to S3 updates. The solution depends on an individual use case, which may require some dev from your side to make it simpler for your marketing teams.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your reply. I've updated the question with more background and context.

Answer (score -1):

I'm unsure what you are asking here, because to "update" a static website, surely you must have some technical knowledge in the very basics of web development.

It's important here to define what exactly you mean by update, because again, updating a website and updating a bucket are two completely different things.

Also, S3 has eventual consistency with PUT's (updating) so there will be some minimal downtime.

The easiest way to update an S3 bucket is via the console, and not the CLI. The console is pretty user friendly, and shouldn't take long to get used to.

Comment: there is no downtime for S3, the eventual consistency does not mean the downtime, it only means the new read will only see the updated version when the PUT is eventually propagated across all the data stores that S3 mantains for redundancy

Comment: Well what does downtime mean here? That is basically what I'm saying. The question is vague in terms of, what you want to update, and what you're referring to in downtime.

Comment: Sorry about not being clear. I've updated the question.